# Como usar la libreria matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Buenas tardes, tengo que hacer un programa que lea un archivo .csv con el siguiente formato:

> 15,10,10,15,20,25,25
>   20,20,10,10,-25,25,10

y genere la gráfica del [audiograma](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=audiograma&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUx6C7o7nUAhVEMSYKHazWBSAQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662#imgrc=RbRGWazvM-Wd5M:).

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv, operator

der=[]
izq=[]

def lee_plano():
    j = 0
    csvarchivo = open ('c:\datos2.csv')
    entrada = csv.reader(csvarchivo)
    for reg in entrada:
        if j==0:
            der.append(reg)
            j = j + 1            
        else:
            izq.append(reg)

    csvarchivo.close()

def grafica():
    x=np.array ([125,250,500,1000,2000,4000,8000])
    y=np.array (der)
    y1=np.array (izq)
    print ("eje x" , x)
    print ("valores y" , y)
    print ("valores der" , der)
    print ("valores y1" , y)
    print ("valores izq" , izq)



    plt.plot (x,y)
    plt.show()


lee_plano()
grafica()
```

pero no gráfica nada y obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/main.py", line 115, in <module>
>     grafica()
>   File "C:/main.py", line 110, in grafica
>     plt.plot (x,y)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3161, in plot
>     ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1819, in inner
>     return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1382, in plot
>     for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 381, in _grab_next_args
>     for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
>   File C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 385, in _plot_args
>     x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 244, in _xy_from_xy
> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (7,) and (1, 1)
> ```

¿Podría alguien, por favor, decirme en que estoy fallando?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Freddy. Un par de cosas: estaría bien que añadieras el error que te muestra al completo y a ser posible el csv, o unas cuantas líneas de él si es muy extenso, para poder reproducir el código. Recuerda formatear el código adecuadamente cuando lo pegues aquí, en Python es vital la identación y el formato cobra más importancia aún. Para ello lo pegas, lo seleccionas y pulsas el botón `{}` del editor o Ctrl + k. Si no aportas un ejemplo reproducible o al menos el error va a ser imposible ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Posiblemente estas leyendo mal los datos, con lo que tienes guardas en `derecho` la primera fila solamente y en `izquierdo` el resto de filas. Además, los arrays resultantes son de dos dimenciones y contienen cadenas, por ejemplo `[["20",  "21"]]`. Es también necesario que `x` e `y` tengan el mismo número de elementos. Repito, **es imprescindible que aportes el error y la estructura del csv para poder orientarte**.

Comment: Hola buenas noches, muchas gracias por tus observaciones, pido disculpas la verdad soy bien nuevo en este tema de python y mas en este de pedir la colaboración, no sabía lo de indentar el código, en este momento procedo a pegar el mensaje de error que saca

Comment: MIra el archivo no supe por donde adjuntarlo pero solo tiene dos filas asi 15 10 10 15 20 25 25
20 20 10 10 -25 25 10
el error es este : for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):    in _grab_next_args  for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):   File C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 385, in _plot_args     x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 244, in _xy_from_xy "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape)) ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (7,) and (1, 1)

Comment: disculpa no se ve bien el archivo pero es asi (15,10,10,15,20,25,25) , (20,20,10,10,-25,25,10)

Comment: Freddy para añadir contenido a la pregunta debes hacerlo en la misma pregunta no desde comentarios. Para ello usa el botón `editar` debajo de la pregunta. Como es tu primera vez por aquí la he editado por ti. Comrpueba que el csv tiene esa estructura exacta y una pregunta, ¿la primera fila corresponde al oido derecho y la segunda al izquierdo mientras que las columnas se relacionan con la frecuencia verdad?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que lees de forma incorrecta el csv, con el formato que tiene, lo más simple es usar directamente NumPy para crear un array con él. Se puede hacer con el módulo `csv` o incluso leyendo las filas y usando el método `split` de las cadenas, pero es complicarse sin necesidad:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def grafica():
    datos = None
    with open('C:/datos2.csv', 'rb') as csvarchivo:
        datos = np.genfromtxt(csvarchivo, delimiter=',')

    der = datos[0]
    izq = datos[1]
    x = (125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000)

    plt.plot(x, der)
    plt.plot(x, izq)
    plt.show()

grafica()
```

Si quieres simular la algo como la gráfica que muestras como ejemplo no es muy complicado:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def grafica():
    datos = None
    with open('C:/datos2.csv', 'rb') as csvarchivo:
        datos = np.genfromtxt(csvarchivo, delimiter=',')

    frecuencias = ('125', '250', '500', '1000', '2000', '4000', '8000')
    x = np.arange(len(frecuencias))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # Lineas de fondo diferenciando los gradientes
    ax.hlines([90,70,55,40,25], -0.5, len(frecuencias)-0.5,
              linestyles='-', color = 'steelblue',linewidth=1)

    # Fondos con diferentes gradientes
    ax.axhspan(25, 40, facecolor='steelblue', alpha=0.2)
    ax.axhspan(55, 40, facecolor='steelblue', alpha=0.4)
    ax.axhspan(70, 55, facecolor='steelblue', alpha=0.6)
    ax.axhspan(90, 70, facecolor='steelblue', alpha=0.8)
    ax.axhspan(120, 90, facecolor='royalblue', alpha=0.8)

    # Graficamos los niveles
    ax.plot(x, datos[0], label = 'Oido derecho', color = 'red', linewidth=2,
            marker = 'o', markersize=9, markeredgewidth=2, markerfacecolor='white')
    ax.plot(x, datos[1], label = 'Oido izquierdo',color='darkslateblue',linewidth=2,
            marker = 'x', markersize=9, markeredgewidth=2)

    # Configuramos los labels de ambos ejes
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(frecuencias)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(120, -20, -10))
    ax.set_ylim(120,-10)

    # Cambiamos el eje x a la parte superior
    ax.xaxis.tick_top()
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')


    # Etiquetas de los ejes
    plt.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
    plt.ylabel('Nivel auditivo (dB)')

    # Leyenda
    plt.legend(loc='lower center',bbox_to_anchor=[0.5, -0.1], ncol=2)

    # Eliminamos los margenes en lo ejes
    ax.margins(0) 

    # Mostra la cuadrícula de fondo
    ax.grid()

    # Mostrar la gráfica
    plt.show()


grafica()
```

**Entrada (csv):**

> 10,10,13,20,40,70,60
>   15,20,10,30,50,65,70

**Salida (Matplotlib 2.0.2):**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: buenos días, primero que todo muchas gracias por tu ayuda, copie el programa (el segundo, la gráfica) tal cual como me lo indicaste, utilice el mismo archivo csv que me enviaste pero me sigue sacando este error: File C:\Python34..", line 60, in <module> grafica(), File "C:\Python34...py", line 28, in grafica marker = 'o', markersize=9, markeredgewidth=2,markerfacecolor='white')   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1898, in inner.. "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (7,) and (1,)

Comment: ¿@FREDDYLLANOS estas leyendo el csv con el código que puse solamente? Mi función lee los datos directamente del csv usando numpy.genfromtxt. El código está probado con ese csv y no genera ningún error.  Añade `print datos` después del `with` a ver que contiene el array, ese error indica que `x` tiene 7 elementos e `y` solo uno, eso no debe  pasar con mi código sin modificar y el csv con esa estructura exacta. Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, mira que fue raro lo único que hice fue abril el archivo.csv con el block de notas , lo guarde en otra ruta,lo cerré y funciono perfecto, gracias de verdad, por favor dime como debo hacer para indicar que la respuesta tuya fue acertada y cerrar la pregunta

Comment: Pues si que es raro @FREDDYLLANOS .... Para aceptar una respuesta solo tienes que  dar click en el simbolo de check que aparece debajo de la puntuación. Mirate este enlace para saber cómo hacerlo y para más información: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas). Saludos.