# Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

Muchas veces cuando estoy trabajando con variables, funciones de distintas librerías, datos, etc. En Python, recibo errores y **todos son distintos pero muy parecidos** pareciendo que apuntan al mismo error:

`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (5,)`

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (6,)`

`ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 64 for`

`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 600), indices imply (2, 576)`

Por ejemplo el primero de ellos me sucede con este código de la librería `matplotlib`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(5)

plt.plot(x, y)
```

Como digo, los errores son relativamente parecidos, siempre hablan de las dimensiones o la forma (shape or dimensions).

**¿Qué significa este tipo de `ValueError` que siempre habla de shapes y dimensiones?** ¿Cómo se puede solucionar?

Comment: buena idea, se podrían ir documentando en la wiki de [tag:python] y o de [tag:pandas], etc, así como marcar como duplicadas todas las que hayas detectado hasta la fecha

Comment: Genial! Voté a favor del duplicado en todos los casos que has marcado. Con wiki me refiero a documentar la pregunta en [la página wiki de python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info), en la sección _Preguntas populares_

Comment: Te felicito. Con esta publicación se han eliminado gran cantidad de preguntas duplicadas. Buen ojo para elegir el tema.

Comment: sería bueno hacer ping (vía chat o comentarios) a otros usuarios habituales en estas etiquetas para que voten también como duplicado las otras preguntas y así el trabajo quede niquelado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero tenemos que ver que es un `ValueError`, según Python se define de la siguiente manera:

> Ocurre cuando una operación o función recibe un argumento que es del
> tipo correcto pero con un valor inapropiado

En concreto **cuando se refieren a su forma (shape) o dimensiones**, quiere decir que:

**La función no acepta que las variables que le has pasado tengan esa forma, longitud (tamaño), o que matemáticamente la operación que tratas de hacer es imposible.**

Voy a explicarlo con ejemplos prácticos, para ello voy a crear las siguientes variables que utilizaré durante la respuesta

```
#Código base
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [0]

x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
           [1,2,3,4,5,6]])

y = np.array([[1,2], 
           [3,4],
           [5,6]])

z = np.array([[1,1], #fila 1
             [2,1],  #fila 2
             [3,2],  #fila 3
             [0,0],  #fila 4
             [5,2],  #fila 5
             [3, 11]]) #fila 6
```

El error de la librería `matplotlib` quiere decir que la función `plt()` no puedes entregarle dos variables con distinta forma (en este caso longitud). Lo puedo replicar haciendo lo siguiente:

```
plt.plot(a, b)
```

**Salida:** `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (6,) and (1,)`

**Esta función requiere que tanto la variable primera, como la segunda tengan la misma longitud** (lo cual es lógico porque si queremos pintar un gráfico necesitamos dos variables el eje *"X"* y el eje *"Y"* y tienen que ser del mismo tamaño).

Por lo tanto necesitamos que las listas *"a"*(6) y *"b"*(1) tengan el mismo tamaño. Lo cambio para que no me de ningún error en la salida:

```
b = [0,5,10,15,20,25] #Longitud de “b” ahora es 6 igual que “a”
plt.plot(a, b)
```

Efectivamente la función se ejecuta correctamente, porque la lista *"a"* tiene una longitud (tamaño) 6 y la lista *"b"* tiene también longitud 6, algo que requiere dicha función.

Ahora vamos a ver con alguna **función matemática sencilla, como la multiplicación matricial**, para ello tratamos de multiplicar la matriz x con la matriz y:

```
np.dot(x,y)
```

**Salida:** `ValueError: shapes (2,6) and (3,2) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)`

Lo que está ocurriendo es que la operación que estamos tratando de hacer es matemáticamente imposible. No se puede multiplicar una matriz (2,6) con una (3,2), ya que las matemáticas dicen:

> Para que **una matriz *"x"* se pueda multiplicar con una matriz *"y"* el número de columnas de *"x"* debe coincidir con el número de filas de *"y"***

En este caso el número de columnas de *"x"* es 6 y el número de filas de *"y"* es 3. Podríamos evitar el error si usamos la matrix *"x"* junto con la matriz *"z"* en vez de con la matriz *"y"*.

```
np.dot(x,z)
```

**Salida:**

```
array([[57, 85],
       [57, 85]])
```

### Conclusion

Este tipo de errores son también vistos en la mayoría de librerías de dato de Python como `Pandas`, `Scipy`, `matplotlib`, `numpy`, `stats` etc. Especialmente frecuentes también en los paquetes de redes neuronales como son `jax`, `Tensorflow`,`Pytorch`, `Theano`, etc. Muchas veces se dan por errore tontos, como pasar una lista vacia, pasar otra variable a la que inicialmente querías, etc.

**En resumen** siempre que aparece un `ValueError` refiriendose a los *shapes* y *dimensions*. Significa que la longitud (tamaño) o la forma de tus variables, no es valido para la función que estás usado o matemáticamente es incorrecto, y por tanto debes de cambiarlo.