# Problemas para actualizar varias celdas de un DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Dispongo del siguiente DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

# Importación de datos
start = "2016-1-4"
end = "2017-1-4"
iberdrola = pdr.DataReader("IBE.MC", "yahoo", start, end)

inversion_inicial = 1200
    
# Creamos un df con 12 fechas de inversión, con incrementos de 30 días a partir de la fecha de inicio
fechas_posibles_inversion = pd.date_range(start,periods=12,freq='30D')    
# Elimina las fechas fuera del rango de datos conocido
fechas_inversion = fechas_posibles_inversion[fechas_posibles_inversion < df_aux_dca.index[-1]]
# Conseguir las fechas más próximas, con cotizaciones
fechas_cercanas_inversion = np.array(iberdrola.index.searchsorted(fechas_inversion))
# Cantidad que se invertirá en cada fecha
porcion = inversion_inicial/12.0         
iberdrola["acc_compradas"] = 0

df = iberdrola[["Close", "acc_compradas"]]
```

`fechas_cercanas_inversion`  es una lista que contiene el número de orden de las filas en las que deseo introducir datos en la columna `acc_compradas`

En éstas celdas, quiero introducir el valor `porcion`. Lo intento con el siguiente bucle.

```
indices = fechas_cercanas_inversion    
for i in range (0, len(indices)):
    df["acc_compradas"].iloc[indices[i], 1] = porcion / iberdrola.iloc[indices[i], 0]    
    
df
```

Me devuelve dos errores que quisiera interpretar y corregir.

a).- `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed`

b).-   `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

Agradeceré ayuda para resolver estos problemas.

Comment: Hola! Te falta poner de donde sale la variable `df_aux_dca`. El significado del primer errors está aquí [significado de ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions). Y lo segundo no es un error, es un **Warning** .

Comment: Gracias. Es un error. debe ser sustituido por iberdrola

Answer (score -1):

### Para el error a)

La respuesta es que `df["acc_compradas"]` es una lista. El DataFrame es df, la solución es dejar solamente `df.iloc[indices[i], 1]`

Answer (score -1):

Para la b) la solución consiste en sustituir

```
df = iberdrola[["Close", "acc_compradas"]]
```

por

```
df = iberdrola[["Close", "acc_compradas"]].copy()
```

Consultar "https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy"