# Error al reconfigurar un DataFrame utilizando "melt"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Necesito reconfigurar un DataFrame utilizando `melt` de la siguiente manera. Con el script que muestro a continuación, intento poner en una columna denominada  `Nombre`, las etiquetas de las columnas del df. Deseo mantener las fechas del índice en una columna denominada  `Date` y cargar las cotizaciones en una columna denominada `Value`.

Importo las cotizaciones de Yahoo

```
# Importar cotizaciones de Yahoo
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from datetime import datetime, date

 
start = "2000-1-4"
end = date.today()
    
tickers = ["IBE.MC", "R4.MC", "TEF.MC", "^IBEX", "^GSPC",  "^IXIC", "^N225", "^STOXX50E","^DJI"  ]

def get(tickers, start, end):
    def data(ticker):
        return pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
    datas = map(data, tickers)
    return pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker','Date']) 
all_data = get(tickers, start, end)

# Resetear el índice para que todo sean columnas
just_closing_prices = all_data[['Adj Close']].reset_index()
just_closing_prices[:5]

""" Movimos las fechas a una columna porque ahora queremos pivotar la Fecha como índice 
y mostrar cada valor de Ticker en una columna:
"""
df = just_closing_prices.pivot_table(values = "Adj Close", index = "Date", columns = "Ticker")

cartera = df.rename(columns = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "R4.MC":"Renta4", 
                               "^IBEX":"Ibex35", "^GSPC":"S&P500", "^IXIC": "Nasdaq", 
                               "^N225":"Nikkey_225", "^DJI":"DowJons", "^STOXX50E":"Eurostoxx50" })
```

Filtro un rango de fechas.

```
# Fecha de inicio del análisis
start = "2016-1-4"
# Fecha de final del análisis.
#end = "2020-9-15"
end = datetime.now()
datos_filtrados = cartera[start: end]
datos_filtrados.reset_index(inplace=True)
datos_filtrados[:3]
```

Y finalmente, reconfiguro el df.

```
# Utilizando "melt", reconfiguro el DataFrame
valores_cartera = pd.melt(datos_filtrados, id_vars =['Date'], value_vars = datos_filtrados.columns[0:])
# Reorganiza las columnas
valores_cartera = valores_cartera[["variable", "Date", "value"]]
valores_cartera.rename(columns={'variable': 'Nombre', "value":"Valor"}, inplace=True)
valores_cartera
```

Me devuelve el error siguiente.

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-92828b9c16c8> in <module>
      1 # Utilizando "melt", reconfiguro el DataFrame
      2 
----> 3 valores_cartera = pd.melt(datos_filtrados, id_vars =['Date'], value_vars = datos_filtrados.columns[0:])
      4 # Reorganiza las columnas
      5 valores_cartera = valores_cartera[["variable", "Date", "value"]]

~/anaconda3/envs/plotly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/melt.py in melt(frame, id_vars, value_vars, var_name, value_name, col_level, ignore_index)
    134         mdata[col] = np.asanyarray(frame.columns._get_level_values(i)).repeat(N)
    135 
--> 136     result = frame._constructor(mdata, columns=mcolumns)
    137 
    138     if not ignore_index:

~/anaconda3/envs/plotly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    466 
    467         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 468             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    469         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    470             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~/anaconda3/envs/plotly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    281             arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    282         ]
--> 283     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    284 
    285 

~/anaconda3/envs/plotly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype, verify_integrity)
     81 
     82         # don't force copy because getting jammed in an ndarray anyway
---> 83         arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
     84 
     85         columns = ensure_index(columns)

~/anaconda3/envs/plotly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in _homogenize(data, index, dtype)
    349                     val = dict(val)
    350                 val = lib.fast_multiget(val, oindex._values, default=np.nan)
--> 351             val = sanitize_array(
    352                 val, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False, raise_cast_failure=False
    353             )

~/anaconda3/envs/plotly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    494     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
    495         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
--> 496             raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")
    497         else:
    498             subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te está diciendo que tienes un error con las dimensiones, si quieres saber más sobre estos errores puedes leer [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

En concreto los datos deben ser unidimensionales `Data must be 1-dimensional` y tu en el parámetro `value_vars` le estás pasando también la columna `Date`, que ya se la habías pasado en `id_vars` por lo que `Pandas` al hacer las transformaciones internas, usando `pd.pivot_table()` **aumenta la dimensión.**

Tu error se corrige haciendo que coja todas las columnas excepto `Date`, para ello en esta linea empezamos a contar las columnas desde la segunda con `datos_filtrados.columns[1:]`. Quedaría así:

```
valores_cartera = pd.melt(datos_filtrados, id_vars =['Date'], value_vars = datos_filtrados.columns[1:])
```

### Compresión del slicing

Cuando se hace slicing, la primera posición es incluida y la segunda NO.

En cualquier iterable `iterable[0:]` no es útil ya que nos devuelve exactamente el mismo iterable por que le estamos diciendo que coja todas las posiciones **incluida la cero** hasta el final

Podría servir para copiar el iterable, pero en ese caso es más simple usar `iterable[:]`