# Estoy entrenando mi red neuronal, pero me sale el siguiente error. ¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

```
#Copilando red neuronal / Descenso de gradiente estocástica
classifier.compile( optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics= ['accuracy'])

#Ajustando red neuronal en set de entrenamiento
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=100)
```

**ERROR**

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 11 but received input with shape (None, 6)`
```

Comment: Estas usando tensorflow? keras? O que?.  También verifica la longitud de los datos que le pasas, pues el error dice que la longitud está mal (además que tienes un `None`)

Comment: Estoy utlizando tensorflow y keras

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quiere decir este error es lo siguiente:

1. Has creado una red neuronal con una primera capa indicandole el parámetro `input_shape`, es decir el tamaño de entrada de tus datos
2. Cuando la vas a entrenar `classifier.fit` le pasas un tamaño de datos que no es el que has declarado y la red neuronal te lanza un `ValueError` que te dice que en la primera capa tu le has dicho que va a recibir unos input con cierto tamaño (`shape`) pero después le has pasado otro.

**El problema y la solución por tanto puede estár en dos sitios**:

- Has declarado mal el input en la capa de entrada
- Tus datos de entreanmiento `X_train` no tienen la forma (o dimensiones) que deberían tener y tienes que transformarlos con `.reshape()`

Este tipo de problemas son de los más frecuentes al comenzar con redes neuronales, el conseguir cuadrar las dimensiones y formas de los datos y la red neurona. Te recomiendo leer esta otra pregunta [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)